# Unable to get Oauth2 working in latest version of Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get a simple oauth2 application running using the latest Spring boot version 1.5.2.RELEASE.

I followed all the steps [spring-boot-oauth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2) till they tell you "What Just Happened" but after configuring application.yml, running the application didn't work and gave following error -

```
WARN 27759 [main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.opentable.DemoApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration due to org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake) 
ERROR 27759 [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b07a0d6: startup date [Thu Mar 30 15:06:55 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Do I need to create a configuration class explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

It required following dependency to be added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple) is wrong. The two ways it mentioned to obtain spring boot application to start with generated wrong pom.xml.

After I added above actuator dependency, things worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```